# Bundle woff and ttf files into 1 file

Tags: html, fonts

Is there a way to bundle woff files (and ttf files as well) into 1 file? Just like we can do with JS using tools like grunt-concat, webmake ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bundle the woff assets into your CSS with base64.

Inside your @font-face declaration:

```
url('data:application/x-font-woff;base64,myVeryLongBase64StringGoesHere...');
```

This may increase the asset's file size. In my experience this is usually by around 20% - roughly the same size as the equivalent TTF file. Much of this may be recovered with a gzip-capable server. The tradeoff is acceptable for me, but YMMV.

As is often recommended when embedding blobs in CSS - keep them all in a separate stylesheet, cited after your base style. Otherwise, the client may be waiting for the fonts to load before they see your content as intended.